# HTTPS for Amazon S3 static website

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to host a HTTPS-only static website using Amazon S3 and CloudFront. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Set up an S3 bucket for static website hosting and put my website files in it
2. Created a CloudFront distribution and pointed it to the S3 bucket
3. Added a CNAME record in my domain's nameservers for the `www` subdomain pointing to the CloudFront bucket.

So far, so good - I can access my website using the `www.example.com` address. However, I want the site to be available via HTTPS only, for which I bought an SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

Now, the question is:

1. Is there a way to install this third-party SSL certificate on my S3-hosted website?
2. Is there a way to have an automatic http to https redirect with this setup?

Comment: Can I do it in free of cost?

Comment: You can get an SSL cert from Amazon for free, and it automatically renews. https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/ Scroll down to the dollar sign icon : )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it  does not deal with programming

Comment: Why not move the question to ServerFault?

Comment: @nueverest Because it's too old to migrate.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, as of today you can do it at no charge.

You can now use HTTPS with CNAMEs on CloudFront as it now supports custom SSL certificates using Server Name Indication (SNI): http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2014/03/server-name-indication-sni-and-http-redirection-for-amazon-cloudfront.html

I managed to set up a free Class 1 StartSSL cert for my CloudFront distributed static site on S3  without too much trouble (see: [CloudFront error when serving over HTTPS using SNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282137/cloudfront-error-when-serving-over-https-using-sni)).

Comment: The caveat here is it doesn't work for some types of older browsers... but that's an awesome alternative to paying $600/month!

Comment: Detailed guide: https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-ssl-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3/

Comment: Feedback:  bryce fisher's guide was very good.

Comment: There's a subtlety here. You can have HTTPS for an S3 bucket [**if it is not configured for website hosting**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html). See the Note that says "The website endpoints do not support https."

Comment: OK, to get past "subtlety" and describe in plain English, here's my shot at it. An S3 bucket with static web page content (html) can be turned into a web site with a few clicks. This web site can only use http.  If you want https, you have to use AWS's Cloudfront service and configure it for SNI to get https for free. (A few very old or odd browsers do not support SNI.) The html and other resources can be stored on S3 at a low cost.  Additionally, if you get the domain name from AWS, you must use their Elastic Load Balance service. Fees are a few cents per gig.

Comment: Doesn't CloudFront add costs even though custom ssl for SNI is free? They charge $0.01 per https request?

Comment: i find it amazing that this answer got awarded the right answer, when it simply doesn't address the question: as stated by @skeller88, s3 https doesn't work for website hosting.

Comment: StartSSL is dead, distrusted by Chrome, FF, Apple; and they do not issue certificates anymore. Consider LetsEncrypt if you want free certificates.

Comment: @skeller88 - so, communication between CloudFront and S3 is not encrypted and can be attacked by the MITM, right? Isn't it a serious security issue for my website (even if it uses HTTPS with CloudFront)?

Answer (score 36):

On 2016-01-21 AWS launched **AWS Certificate Manager**, which is a **free** service that allows you to issue a SSL certificate to be used with Elastic Load Balancer and Cloud Front (along with S3 too).

You can learn more at:
https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

And you can check how to deploy your S3 + Cloudfront website with free SSL from AWS at:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/

Comment: I just set this up for my site this morning. It's a static site hosted in s3. It was _super_ easy. I simply went to the acm manager, requested a cert, putzed around with my email settings for a few hours (ended up making my WHOIS info public while I waited for the confirmation email), and then set up route53 to point at the cloudfront endpoint. Very happy I found this comment.

Comment: @paranoid With this can I host my s3 website as https-only?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare yes, you can!

Comment: Put the HTTPS link in the CNAME record in Route53.

Comment: @paranoid not sure what you mean by "cloudfront endpoint".. where do i get that information from?

Comment: @abbood If you go to your cloudfront distributions, select the distribution you want to use and click "distribution settings" (or just click the ID) and in the general tab you'll see "Domain Name". I used that in my route53 record - it's an A record with the alias target of the cloudfront domain name. More can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-alias-target

Answer (score 17):

As of today, Cloudfront offers custom SSL: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Keep in mind, they are charging $600 / month. More details on the link above.

Comment: 600 / month......

Comment: You only pay $600 if you want a dedicated IP address. If you are happy to use SNI (which is not supported by older browsers), no extra charges apply

Comment: If you're willing to support modern browsers only (through SNI), this is now much cheaper: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/03/05/amazon-cloudront-announces-sni-custom-ssl/

Comment: This is FREE now! https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/ Scroll down to the dollar sign icon. Plus I think they renew automatically. And setup is as easy as entering the domains you want on the cert and clicking the validation link in the email that follows.

Answer (score 3):

For me I had to upload a simple React website to S3. 
As barbolo describes you need a certificate to access site through SSL.
If the static site that you want to deploy is simple enough you can:

1. Upload to S3.
2. Do **not** select "Static Website Hosting"
3. Convert all relative links (to css, js, etc) to absolute links.

e.g. from /css/media.css you should convert it to https://s3-region-amazonaws.com/bucket-name/css/media.css (for me I had to change only links in index.html)

4. Make only the contents of bucket public.

Thats it. You can access the index file through https.

A Simple site is a site with a main index.html file that points to some css and js pages.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks

Comment: If your app targets production this is a bad idea.

Comment: sébastien please share with us more details why this is bad idea. We give public read access to objects not to bucket.

Comment: Its a good and simplest way but remember, for every single file in your application the request will travel on internet which will reduce performance of your application. Using CloudFront is the best idea in this scenarios.

Comment: @NiteshB.CloudFront is ass-pain when you need update your S3 objects often

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @wikichen's answer.

From: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

> By default, you can deliver your content to viewers over HTTPS by using your CloudFront distribution domain name in your URLs, for example, https://dxxxxx.cloudfront.net/image.jpg.
>
> If you want to deliver your content over HTTPS using your own domain name and your own SSL certificate, you can use one of our Custom SSL certificate support features.